# How to reset the timer rxjs?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, nestjs

How to reset the timer if a 401 authorization error occurs?

```
  @Sse('true')
  @HasRole(Role.ADMIN)
  async sse(@Res() response: Response) {
    return timer(0, 44000).pipe(
      map(async () => {
        const result = await this.postService.count();
        response.write(`data: ${result.count}\n\n`);
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: take a look at the `retry` operator

Answer (score 0):

`retry` is what you are looking for :

```
import { map, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

timer(0, 1000)
  .pipe(
    map((i) => {
      if (i > 5) {
        throw new Error();
      }
      return i;
    }),
    retry()
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Will output :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
2
...
```